# Update dbml designer.cs from layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Usually when I want to add a table to my dbml, I drag the table over from my server explorer.

I'm having issues connecting to my database from the Server Explorer, so I decided to just add my class by right-clicking in the designer and selecting Add Class. So I created the class and properties to match up with the database.

But for some reason, none of the code was generated for it in the designer.cs file. Is there a way to generate all that code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to right-click on the DBML file and choose "Run Custom Tool"

Comment: Well that did something. When I ran it, it made changes to the designer file, but I don't know what it did. It didn't add the code for my table.